# how do enable sorting in an angular ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Im trying to add sorting to a simple ag grid but i keep getting an error saying :
Can't bind to 'enableSorting' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.

Here is the template:

```
<ag-grid-angular
 [enableSorting]="true"
 [rowData]="rowData"
 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

i even tried using a GridOptions object but it wont recognize enableSorting or enableFilter but it does recognize pagination. what am i doing wrong?

I'm following [this](https://blog.ag-grid.com/get-started-with-angular-grid-in-5-minutes/#angular-grid-sorting) introductory guide on ag grid's blog.
without the sorting part the grid works as expected so i dont think its something related to configuration(imported module and import array) but i double checked anyway and its all setup correctly!
angular version 10 ag grid version 24.

Comment: Don't follow the blog since it's outdated. Go to the official [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php) to see working examples, if something changes, they will update the example in the docs rather than the blog you read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would recommend using GridOptions again - as it's likely you'll want to specify how many other parts of Ag-Grid look and feel.

If you'd like sorting to be available on all of the columns in your grid, simply use the following:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true
  }
}
```

And then provide grid options to your Ag-Grid in the html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
 [rowData]="rowData"
 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: this solution works but im still wondering what was wrong in my approach seeing as i was following an official ag grid blog guide. did they change something since that guide get published?

Comment: @sroool If you're happy with the answer, please accept and upvote. As to what was wrong, they may have changes the syntax as there have been a number of major semantic version changes in the Ag-Grid since that article was written. The approach I've provided is not expected to change anytime soon, so I'd go with that moving forward. It also make sense to define your grid's config in one place and provide it in the html, to make it more readable.

Comment: thats understandable, that guide is 2 years old. i upvoted your solution but i have less than 15 rep so it doesnt publicly show it. thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem while upgrading from ag-grid 19 to 24.  It appears that since version 20 `enableFilter` has been removed at the `GridOptions` level and must be set per `ColDef`.  [See here for more on that.](https://github.com/BBj-Plugins/BBjGridExWidget/issues/97)

And although I couldn't find any similar documentation on it, I suspect the same thing has happened with `enableSorting`. It seems it was thus replaced with sortable at the `ColDef` level as @cmprogram mentioned in his/her answer.

This is speculation, but if anyone can find the documentation on that change please respond in the comments and I'll add it to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> try like this..

```
gridOptions: {
 
    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true
    },
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name' },
        { field: 'age' },
     
        { field: 'address', sortable: false },
    ]
}



    <ag-grid-angular
            [rowData]="rowData | async"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            [enableSorting]="true"
        >
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: this solution doesnt work, compiler still says "Can't bind to 'enableSorting' since..."